# Cypress.env() always returns undefined

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, cypress

I have my cypress.config.ts like this

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  pageLoadTimeout: 360000,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 60000,
  env: {
    EMAIL: "random@mail.com",
    PASSWORD: "password"
  }
});
```

And when I try to use this
`cy.get("#emailField").type(Cypress.env('EMAIL'));` in my test is always returns undefined. I tried moving the env into JSON file `cypress.env.json` but that didn't help. I also tried switching to javascript but the result was the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there is little information about the problem but did you try `cy.log(Cypress.env('EMAIL'))`
to see if env variable its working fine, becasue there can be problem with selector.